# iMac 27" Mid 2010 RAM Upgrade

Tags: imac, upgrade, memory

I have an iMac 27", Mid 2010 (11,3 model). Can it take 8GB RAM modules? Apple's website http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht4255 says "The maximum amount of RAM you can install in your computer is 16 GB (a 4 GB SO-DIMM in each slot)." But people say that 8 GB sticks ARE in fact supported. For instance, according to OWC, (http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/memory/iMac/2010/DDR3_21.5_27) 8.0GB PC10600 DDR3 Module (http://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/1333DDR3S8GB/) works.

In particular, can I use Transcend JetRAM DDR3 8GB JM1333KSH-8G http://www.flipkart.com/transcend-jetram-ddr3-8-gb-laptop-dram-jm1333ksh-8g/p/itmdfzhzd2v8mtza?pid=RAMDFZHXPYRVVGJA ?

And how about Transcend JetRAM DDR3 4GB JM1333KSN-4G http://www.flipkart.com/transcend-ddr3-4-gb-laptop-dram-jm1333ksn-4g/p/itmdv6g6gnnsnkvc?pid=RAMD2RYPNQKZ5TJV ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is 'Yes, it will take them.' 8GB sticks were 'unsupported' at that time, but just turned out they worked.

I have an old Mac Pro that has the same 'unofficial' double-storage. Shoudld take 32GB 8x4, does in fact take 64GB, 8x8.

It's only the 21" iMac from that series that really can only take 16GB

Ref - [Everymac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/imac-aluminum-faq/imac-intel-aluminum-21.5-inch-27-inch-how-to-upgrade-memory.html) & personal experience.

For specifically which sticks it will take, OWC doesn't ship here so I've never tested their algorithms. I would use [Crucial's](http://www.crucial.com) detector tool, which has never let me down.